# py2exe issue with watchdog library

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, exe, py2exe

I am currently attempting to greate a .exe file with my Python script. When I attempt to run the file, I am getting this message from the command line when I run the .exe:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                
File "operation.py",     line 2, in <module>                                        
File "watchdog\observers\__init__.pyc", line 79, in <module>                    
File "watchdog\observers\polling.pyc", line 37, in <module>                     
File "watchdog\utils\dirsnapshot.pyc", line 59, in <module>                   
ImportError: No module named pathtools.path
```

Can somebody explain to me what the issue is? I have verified that watchdog is installed correctly.

Edit - Based on the feedback that I have received, it appears that I need to include the watchdog .egg file. Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import pkg_resources

eggs = pkg_resources.require("watchdog")
from setuptools.archive_util import unpack_archive
for egg in eggs:
   if os.path.isdir(egg.location):
       sys.path.insert(0, egg.location)
       continue
   unpack_archive(egg.location, eggdir)
eggpacks = set()
eggspth = open("build/eggs.pth", "w")
for egg in eggs:
   print egg
   eggspth.write(os.path.basename(egg.location))
   eggspth.write("\n")
   eggpacks.update(egg.get_metadata_lines("top_level.txt"))
eggspth.close()
eggpacks.remove("pkg_resources")

setup(console=['operation.py'])
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Kevin Li\Documents\Projects\artona-image-monitor\modules\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
from setuptools.archive_util import unpack_archive
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module> from setuptools.extension import Extension
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 33, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 29, in _get_unpatched

AssertionError: distutils has already been patched by <class py2exe.Distribution at 0x0270EF48>
```

Comment: Have you tried [this suggestion](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/DealingWithImportError) on the py2exe.org FAQ?

Comment: Thanks. I have revised my question accordingly.